# What is the meaning of in the flesh?

Tags: phrase-meaning, synonyms

In the [Cambridge learners dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/flesh?q=in%20the%20flesh) the meaning of the phrase `in the flesh` is described as follows:

> **in the flesh:** in real life and not on television or in a film

But I want to know if it can be used in a more general way as a synonym of `in reality`? For instance suppose the following sentences:

> I have always dreamed of having my own business but it is very
> difficult **in reality**.
>
> I have always dreamed of having my own business but it is very
> difficult **in the flesh**

These sentences do not have anything to do with TV and movies. So is it correct to use `in the flesh` instead of `in reality`? do they have the same meaning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

“in the flesh” is used specifically for people, meaning that their actual human flesh is present rather than some representation of them.

Your dream becoming reality wouldn’t be “in the flesh” unless that dream is specifically about a person. A business has no flesh.